# Did abortion rights activists burn effigies of fetuses at a protest?

Tags: abortion

The [Ask Dr Brown](https://www.facebook.com/AskDrBrown/videos/2367473096668263?sfns=mo) Facebook page shared a a video a crowd around a street fire stating:

> Abortion activists burn unborn babies in effigy

This same video was shared on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/genuinelygia_/status/1159201863561932800) with a misleading text suggesting that the dolls were actually fetuses, which appears to have been believed by people unfamiliar with the concept of [burning an effigy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effigy).

I can’t find a related news article for this. Did abortion rights activists burn effigies of fetuses at a protest?

Comment: Burning "in effigy" would mean they are NOT burning actual unborn babies, but just some sort of doll or figure or the like.

Comment: I looked at the silly video and have 2 comments: they're definitely plastic dolls, not foetuses, and there seem to be 3 (or more) different crowds involved.

Comment: This is tricky, because the tweeter and many of the commenters clearly believe they are real foetuses, but the video also has 'in effigy' in large, clear letters. An answer that just points to the dictionary definition of 'effigy' seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Do you doubt they burnt dolls?

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes, especially in this context.

Comment: Partial answer: The images appear to be (at least substantially) from a July 25, 2018 abortion rights march in Santiago, Chile.